# Angular directive ng-model working for arrays but not string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The `ng-model` directive seems to be lacking a reference to the actual object within the JavaScript, but only for string values. Using the list of dictionary objects and looping over the elements with `ng-repeat` as shown below though, it works.

I can only think that it may be due to returning the array acts like returning a reference to the object, whereas returning the string variable is simply returning the literal string, neutralizing the Angular's ability to do it's two-way data binding and leaving me with a variable that still holds a value of `undefined`.

**Why is my service module below unable to pull the updated value from the view for the variable `gitRelease`?**

In a service module I have this functionality:

```
(function () { //start iife

    'use strict';

    angular.module('gms.autoDeploy')
        .factory('AutoDeployService', ["$http", "$q", "$log", "$cookies", "APP_CONFIGS", "SweetAlert", "$timeout", "GridSettingsService", "APP_USER", AutoDeployService]);

    function AutoDeployService($http, $q, $log, $cookies, APP_CONFIGS, $timeout, SweetAlert, GridSettingsService, APP_USER) {

        var tibcoCopyJobs = [];
        var gitRelease = "";

        function addNewTibcoCopyJob() {
            tibcoCopyJobs.push({
                sourceServer: "",
                sourcePath: "",
                destinationServer: "",
                destinationPath: ""
            });
        }

        function getTibcoCopyJobs() { return tibcoCopyJobs; }
        function getGitRelease(){ return gitRelease; }

        function extractFormData() {
            console.log(gitRelease);
            for (var i = 0; i < tibcoCopyJobs.length; i++) {
                console.log(tibcoCopyJobs[i]);
            }
        }

        return {
            addNewTibcoCopyJob:             addNewTibcoCopyJob,
            getTibcoCopyJobs:               getTibcoCopyJobs,
            getGitRelease:                  getGitRelease,
            extractFormData:                extractFormData
        };
    } //end AutoDeployService
}()); //end iife
```

Using it with this controller:

```
angular.module("gms.autoDeploy").controller('AutoDeployController', ['$scope', '$compile', 'AutoDeployService',
function ($scope, $compile, AutoDeployService) {

        var model = this;

        init();

        function init() {
            model.tibcoCopyJobs = AutoDeployService.getTibcoCopyJobs();
            model.gitRelease = AutoDeployService.getGitRelease();
        }

        function btn_addNewTibcoCopy() { AutoDeployService.addNewTibcoCopyJob(); }

        function btn_extractFormData() { AutoDeployService.extractFormData(); }

        model.btn_addNewTibcoCopy = btn_addNewTibcoCopy;
        model.btn_extractFormData = btn_extractFormData;
    }
]);
```

To give functionality to this view:

```
<div ng-controller="AutoDeployController as autoDeploy">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="autoDeploy.gitRelease" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px" ng-repeat="item in autoDeploy.tibcoCopyJobs track by $index">
        <legend>Copy</legend>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Source Server..." ng-model="item.sourceServer">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Source Path..." ng-model="item.sourcePath">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination Server..." ng-model="item.destinationServer">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination Path..." ng-model="item.destinationPath">
    </fieldset>
</div>

<button ng-click="autoDeploy.btn_extractFormData()">extract</button>
<button ng-click="autoDeploy.btn_addNewTibcoCopy()">TIBCO copy</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try turning your string into an object with one parameter. e.g. `var data = {gitRelease: ''} `. To get two-way binding to work correctly you have to use reference to objects or arrays, instead of literals. Also you have to empty and repopulate the array to change it, or if you want to reassign you need to shallow watch the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have explained why in your question. Array is returned by reference, whereas string is just copied by value. But I will try to make it a bit more clear.

When you do

```
model.gitRelease = AutoDeployService.getGitRelease();
```

the model object will create property getRelease like this:

```
{getRelease: "", ... (more properties from the ctrl)}
```

so whatever you update in the view it will just update the getRelease in the controller.

One possible fix is like what Jags mentioned in the comment.

Or you can make a reference to your service in the ctrl

```
var model = this;
model.autoDeployService = AutoDeployService;
```

In your view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="autoDeploy.autoDeployService.gitRelease" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY">
```

that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, do you use an inspection tool to see the model object details, or is there documentation describing the model object layout? As for the solution, I wasn't sure of the efficiency or the conformity to separation of concerns w.r.t. the MVC approach by directly referencing the service from the view, so I made a new dictionary in the service to hold simple string variables, and I just treat it like I do with the `tibcoCopyJobs` object. Essentially using `var singleEntryData = { gitRelease: "" };` and `... ng-model="autoDeploy.singleEntryData.gitRelease" ...`

Comment: I usually use inspection tool from the browser where you can set a break point in the source code and inspect the objects. I don't think there is a problem directly referencing the service. It depends on cases by cases, or preference. Imagine the case where you have a big model with lots of data and have to share data between multiple controllers, directly reference using service will be one of the good ways to go.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Considering that your implementation would be a better practice for large projects, I'll give this one to you.